# Cannot see the desktop panels and desktop shortcut software control panels

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, desktop-environments

When booting up Ubuntu 14.04.4 by virtualbox, there are no desktop panels and the shortcut application program with no select items panel doesn't appear, as shown in the image.

How can I fix these two problems?

[image: desktop panels and application programs panels]

Comment: Have you turned on Auto Hide Launcher in settings?

Comment: I am not quite sure. How can I disable this Auto Hide Launcher ? I just only reboot the system then it shows this. Before reboot, I killed one big folder but it seems not related to the Desktop setting !

Comment: I think that I did not turn on Auto Hide Launcher!